# Program stuck in a loop cycle despite the last function not being part of a loop

Tags: c, loops

Okay so Im relatively new to C and basically I've written a program that takes the user through a tennis tournament with 4 rounds. The program works perfectly up until the last function(FR), after I input the winning number, the program cuts straight back to R1, how is this possible? How can I get the program to end after the final round?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define R1CONTESTANTS 16
#define R2CONTESTANTS 8
#define R3CONTESTANTS 4
#define FRCONTESTANTS 2
#define WINNER 1


int main(void)
{
  GetNames();
  R1();
  R2();
  R3();
  FR();  
  return 0;
}

int GetNames()
{
  char Name[R1CONTESTANTS][20];
  int n;

  printf("Hello and Welcome to the 2014 Tennis Knockout Competition!\n");
  printf("Please enter the names of all 16 players (MAX 20 CHARACTERS): \n");
  /*Get Names loop*/
    for(n = 0; n < 16 ; n++)
    {
      printf("%d >>", n+1);
      scanf("%20s", Name[n]);
      fflush(stdin); 
    }
  R1(Name);
}

int R1(char Name[][20])
{
  char R2Name[R2CONTESTANTS][20];
  int m, i;
  int Winner[8];

  system("clear");
  printf("WELCOME TO ROUND 1! IT WILL CONSIST OF 8 MATCHES! GOOD LUCK!");
  for(m = 0, i = 0; m < 8 ; m++, i+=2)
        {
          printf("\nMatch %d of 8.\n", m+1);
          printf("\n(1) %s v %s (2)\n", Name[i], Name[i+1]);
          printf("\nWinner of Match %d(1/2): ", m+1);
          scanf("%d", &Winner[m]);
          fflush(stdin);
          switch(Winner[m])
          {
            case 1 : strncpy(R2Name[m], Name[i], 20);break;
            case 2 : strncpy(R2Name[m], Name[i+1], 20);break;
            default : printf("\nSomething went wrong. Please try again.\n");break;
          }
        }
  R2(R2Name);
}

int R2(char R2Name[][20])
{
  char R3Name[R3CONTESTANTS][20];
  int m, i;
  int R2Winner[4];

  system("clear");
  printf("WELCOME TO ROUND 2! IT WILL CONSIST OF 4 MATCHES! GOOD LUCK!");
  for(m = 0, i = 0; m < 4; m++, i+=2)
      {
        printf("\nMatch %d of 4.\n", m+1);
        printf("\n(1) %s v %s (2)\n", R2Name[i], R2Name[i+1]);
        printf("\nWinner of Match %d(1/2): ", m+1);
        scanf("%d", &R2Winner[m]);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch(R2Winner[m])
          {
            case 1 : strncpy(R3Name[m], R2Name[i], 20);break;
            case 2 : strncpy(R3Name[m], R2Name[i+1], 20);break;
            default : printf("\nSomething went wrong. Please try again.\n");break;
          }
       }
  R3(R3Name);
}

int R3(char R3Name[][20])
{
  char FRName[FRCONTESTANTS][20];
  int m, i;
  int R3Winner[2];

  system("clear");
  printf("WELCOME TO THE SEMI FINALS! GOOD LUCK!");
  for(m = 0, i = 0; m < 2; m++, i+=2)
         {
            printf("\nMatch %d of 2.\n", m+1);
            printf("\n(1) %s v %s (2)\n", R3Name[i], R3Name[i+1]);
            printf("\nWinner of Match %d(1/2): ", m+1);
            scanf("%d", &R3Winner[m]);
            fflush(stdin);
            switch(R3Winner[m])
            {
              case 1 : strncpy(FRName[m], R3Name[i], 20);break;
              case 2 : strncpy(FRName[m], R3Name[i+1], 20);break;
              default : printf("\nSomething went wrong. Please try again.\n");break;
            }
         }
  FR(FRName);
}

int FR(char FRName[][20])
{
  int FRWinner;
  char OWName[WINNER][20];

  system("clear");
  printf("YOU HAVE MADE IT TO THE FINAL ROUND! GOOD LUCK!");
  printf("\n\n(1) %s v %s (2)\n", FRName[0], FRName[1]);
  printf("\nWinner of Match and Tournament(1/2): ");
  scanf("%d", &FRWinner);
  fflush(stdin);
  switch(FRWinner)
  {
    case 1 : strncpy(OWName[0], FRName[0], 20);break;
    case 2 : strncpy(OWName[0], FRName[1], 20);break;
    default : printf("Something went wrong.");break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Never call `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: my lecturer makes us put it in, ill drop marks otherwise

Comment: int R3(char R3Name[][20]) in function but you not pass any parameters you calling as R3(); why?

Comment: Wow - your lecturer is an idiot then, because `fflush(stdin)` is not only unnecessary but also results in undefined behaviour in general (although it is supported on some platforms, but this is non-standard).

Comment: You have flow problem there.

Comment: the c standard says about fflush: `If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: Note that your code is in serious need of re-factoring - you have a bunch of almost identical routines which you have copy-pasted and made small changes to - this is a serious code smell - you should consolidate these routines into one.

Comment: Those that can do, those that can't ... `fflush` operates on an *output stream*. To operate on input stream is *undefined behaviour*. Something to tell your lecturer: constructively of course. Nobody is perfect.

Comment: In `main()`, you are calling methods without passing any parameters, while by definition, those methods actually need a parameter!

Comment: Also note that you have no function prototypes - did you forget to enable compiler warnings or are you just ignoring them ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `R1` from `GetNames`, and then again from `main`. You have each step calling its successor, as well as `main` calling each step.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call R1(), R2(), etc... in main because R1 is called at the end of GetNames, R2 is called at the end of R1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit funny, you seem to chain the methods together, and also call them in order from main.

So your current program flow is.

```
 GetNames() -> R1() -> R2() -> R3() -> FR()
 R1() -> R2() -> R3() -> FR()
 R2() -> R3() -> FR()
 R3() -> FR()
 FR()
```

And then there is the whole deal about not passing parameters, which would be an happy accident if the compiler had refused to compile the mess or it just crashed immediately.

Now you have something that seems to run on your hands, dangerous stuff.